# Given $a,b,c >0$ such that $abc=1/8$, show that $a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2 \geq 15/16$

Tags: inequality

Given $a,b,c >0$ such that $abc=1/8$, show that

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2 \geq 15/16$$

I have already tried to show this with the AM-GM inequality:

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+1/(8c)^2+1/(8a)^2+1/(8b)^2$$
$$=\left(a^2+\frac{1}{64a^2}\right)+\left(b^2+\frac{1}{64b^2}\right)+\left(c^2+\frac{1}{64c^2}\right)$$

With AM-GM:

$$\sqrt{1/64}=\sqrt{x\cdot \frac{1}{64x}}=\frac{1}{8}\leq \frac{x+1/64x}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\leq x+\frac{1}{64x}$$

But it turns out this is only strong enough to show that

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2=\left(a^2+\frac{1}{64a^2}\right)+\left(b^2+\frac{1}{64b^2}\right)+\left(c^2+\frac{1}{64c^2}\right)\geq \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1827524p12226664, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1154236p5470969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R^+}, abc=\dfrac{1}{8}. \\ \text{Prove that } a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \geq \dfrac {15}{16}.$

Using AM-GM:

$a^2+b^2+c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2 \cdot b^2c^2 \cdot c^2a^2} = 3 \cdot \dfrac {1}{4} + 3\cdot\dfrac{1}{16}=\dfrac{15}{16}.$

Comment: +) Equality fits when $a^2=b^2=c^2, (a, b, c)=\left( \pm \dfrac{1}{2}, \pm \dfrac{1}{2}, \pm \dfrac{1}{2} \right)$.(Doesn't have to be same order decryption.)